# C# add const field using attributes

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

We have class 'SomeClass':

```
namespace Namespace
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        // something
    }
}
```

And attribute 'SomeAttribute':

```
class SomeAttribute : System.Attribute { }
```

**Task:** add to all classes market by SomeAttribute 'public const string Type' field. Modified classes must be following:

```
class SomeClass
{
    // something
    public const string Type = @"Namespace.SomeClass";
}
```

**UPD:**

I'm using following approach for message transaction:

```
class Manager
{
    // message has 3 parts:
    // string message = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
    //     typeof(SomeClass).ToString(),
    //     splitter,
    //     Manager.Serialize(someClassObj)
    // )
    public static string GetType(string message) { /* some code */ }
    public static string Serialize(SomeClass message) { /* XML serialization */ }
    public static SomeClass Deserialize(string message) { /* deserialization */ }
}

class Logic 
{
    public void ProcessMessage(string message)
    {
        switch (Manager.GetType(message))
        {
            case SomeClass.Type:
                {
                    SomeClass msg = Manager.Deserialize(message) as SomeClass;
                    // send message to binded objects
                }
                break;
            case ClassInheritedFromSomeClass.Type:
                {
                    // the same
                }
                break;
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD 2:**

More about messages. At this time I'm using next approach:

```
public class BaseMessage
{
    public const string Type = @"Messages.BaseMessage";
}

public class LoginMessage : BaseMessage
{
    public new const string Type = @"Messages.Client.LoginMessage";

    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Conclusion**

I think best case is to modify Manger like this:

```
class Manager
{
    // create event table

    public Action<BaseMessage> this[string eventName]
    {
        get 
        {
            if (!m_eventTable.ContainsKey(eventName))
            {
                m_eventTable.Add(eventName, new Action<BaseMessage>(message => { }));
            }
            return m_eventTable[eventName]; 
        }
        set
        {
            m_eventTable[eventName] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Send(BaseMessage message, string messageName)
    {
        if (m_eventTable.ContainsKey(messageName) && this[messageName].Method != null)
        {
            this[messageName].Invoke(message);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, Action<BaseMessage>> m_eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Action<BaseMessage>>();
}
```

Comment: why would you need that? `typeof(SomeClass)` is much more versatile...? For example `typeof(SomeClass).FullName`

Comment: And if the value of the constant is different from `typeof(SomeClass).FullName`: Why not put the value directly in the attribute?

Comment: Attributes are Reflection stuff. What you need might be more like a property in a base class returning `GetType().FullName`.

Comment: I know about that case, but I use 'Type' in switch statement that required const values.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest that you should replace the `switch` with `if/else` statements.

Comment: Try to read code of 10 different `if/else` statements and `switch` statement with 10 cases for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Using `switch` with `GetType` is the wrong way to implement polymorphism, because it only checks the most-derived class (breaks extensibility).

In your particular case, where you want the `Manager` to be responsible for the behavior, you might use the `dynamic` keyword and overloaded methods.  But this will again violate SOLID, because it isn't open for extension.

Instead of violating SOLID this way, try to find a way to use virtual methods to perform the type-specific action.